# RequireJS - Nested require calls, how to clean up?

Tags: javascript, django, requirejs

My project is setup using Django and I've been tasked with implementing requireJS throughout the project in an effort to start modularizing our JavaScript.
Because we are using Django that means that we are also using nested templates, which is the start of the complications.

The following is essentially the setup I have working right now:

```
// template.html
<script src="require.js">
<body>
    ... some html ...
    {% include "body.html" %}
</body>
<script>
    requirejs(['static/require/main.js'], function() {
        requirejs(['static/app/template.js']);
    });
</script>

// body.html
<div>
    ... some html ...
</div>
<script>
    requirejs(['static/require/main.js'], function() {
        requirejs(['static/app/body.js']);
    });
</script>


// compiled HTML:
<script src="require.js">
<body>
    ... some html ...
    <div>
        ... some html ...
    </div>
    <script>
        requirejs(['static/require/main.js'], function() {
            requirejs(['static/app/body.js']);
        });
    </script>
</body>
<script>
    requirejs(['static/require/main.js'], function() {
        requirejs(['static/app/template.js']);
    });
</script>


// main.js
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '...'
    }
);

// body.js
define('app/bodyjs', ['jquery'], function() {
    ... some js ...
});


// template.js
define('app/template.js', ['jquery'], function() {
    ... some js ...
});
```

What I want is to be able to clean up the nested requirejs() calls.

I would prefer to do

```
// body.js
define('app/body.js', ['/static/require/main.js', 'jquery'], function () {
    ... some js ...
});
```

But that ends up looking for jquery at /jquery.js, which is incorrect, where the correct path would be /static/lib/jquery.js

Thoughts on how to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(A note before going forward: I see `.js` extensions in all your module names. You should never put a `.js` in a module name unless you have a reason that *forces* you to add the `.js`.)

I take it that `/static/require/main` (no extension) contains your RequireJS configuration. The problem you are running into is that RequireJS loads *all* modules asynchronously but you need to have your configuration loaded *before* anything else is loaded. One solution is to nest `require` calls like you do.

Another solution is to load your configuration synchronously:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="requirejs-config.js"></script>
```

The 1st line loads RequireJS and the 2nd line loads the script that contains the call to `require.config`. It is guaranteed to load before RequireJS loads anything else. You cannot use `data-main` if you do this, as the module named by `data-main` would load before the configuration is loaded.

Another thing I notice in your code is that you call `define` with a module name (1st argument). You should leave the module names out and let `r.js` add them when you optimize your code. The principle here is the same as for extensions, add a module name *only* if you can cite a significant reason for doing so. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Thanks!
That works out perfectly. Had to do a bit of re-working but after an afternoon it's all working fine.

And yeah, no need to put the .js, I was just putting it for clarity :)

Comment: Glad to help! The issue with adding the `.js` is that it changes the rules by which RequireJS resolves paths. Depending on what your config actually contains, it may change nothing but if you change your configuration then it can become a problem. The safe thing to do is to not put the extensions.